# Psalm reports InvalidArrayOffset, but the value will be within bounds

Tags: php, static-analysis, typechecking, psalm-php

When running Psalm on this simple "random string" generator:

```
$letters      = 'abcdefghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz';
$numbers      = '23456789';

$number_count = \strlen($numbers);
$letter_count = \strlen($letters);

$pass = '';

while (\strlen($pass) < 9) {
    $pass .= $letters[\random_int(0, $letter_count - 1)];
}

while (\strlen($pass) < 12) {
    $pass .= $numbers[\random_int(0, $number_count - 1)];
}
```

I get an error (as seen [here](https://psalm.dev/r/7a14bebce5)):

> ERROR: InvalidArrayOffset - 15:11 - Cannot access value on variable $numbers using a int offset, expecting -8|-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7

What I don't understand, is what I get the error on line 11, and not 4 lines earlier, when I'm fetching characters from `$letters`.

I'm doing exactly the same both times, yet on the second one it seems psalm can't infer  the possible return values from `random_int()`, and that they will be within acceptable values. And yet it can the first time.

What I'm doing wrong, and how can I make Psalm understand the code?

I know that the code [works](https://3v4l.org/qU2AO), but I am confused why the first `$pass` assignment does not trigger an error, but the second one does.

Comment: Code seems perfectly fine. Must be an issue with Psalm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine. The issue described here is tracked at https://github.com/vimeo/psalm/issues/5458.